# Python SQlite3: Query WHERE column = column not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I need help with my python code. I am trying to design a GUI with TKinter that will retrieve records in the database with the values in the Entry boxes, without requiring all the boxes to have values.

I am using sqlite3 and have designed this solution:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('tensile_db.db')

# Cursor
c = conn.cursor()

# Query Database
c.execute("SELECT * FROM tensile_test_table WHERE experiment_id = :exp_id, library_id = :lib_id, creation_date = :creat_date, creation_time = :creat_time, created_by = :creat_by, row_num = :row_num, column_num = :col_num, total_number_of_properties = :tot_num_prop, sample_type = :samp_type, youngs_modulus_pascals_ = :ym, comments = :comm", 
           {'exp_id': 'experiment_id' if exp_id.get() == '' else exp_id.get(),
            'lib_id': lib_id.get() if lib_id.get() != '' else 'library_id',
            'creat_date': creat_date.get() if creat_date.get() != '' else 'creation_date',
            'creat_time': creat_time.get() if creat_time.get() != '' else 'creation_time',
            'creat_by': creat_by.get() if creat_by.get() != '' else 'creation_by',
            'row_num': row_num.get() if row_num.get() != '' else 'row_num',
            'col_num': col_num.get() if col_num.get() != '' else 'column_num',
            'tot_num_prop': tot_num_prop.get() if tot_num_prop.get() != '' else 'total_number_of_properties',
            'samp_type': samp_type.get() if samp_type.get() != '' else 'sample_type',
            'ym': ym.get() if ym.get() != '' else 'youngs_modulus_pascals_',
            'comm': comm.get() if comm.get() != '' else 'comments'
              }
          )
records = c.fetchall()
print(records)

# Loop through Results
print_records = ''
for record in records:
    print_records += str(record) + '\n'
```

In this solution, I should get all the rows when the cells are empty, due to the condition on the dictionary. However, it returns an empty list in that case and when any of the entries are empty, but it does return a list of the wanted row when all values are included.

I tried to troubleshoot by simplifying my select statement to only one column and found out the problem is with the dictionary. If I change my statement to this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM tensile_test_table WHERE experiment_id = experiment_id")
```

I get all the records in the database. However, if I change it to this:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM tensile_test_table WHERE experiment_id = :exp_id", 
           {'exp_id': 'experiment_id'})
```

It leads to an empty list. If I include the condition in the dictionary `'exp_id': 'experiment_id' if exp_id.get() == '' else exp_id.get()` and enter a value present in the database in the Entry box of the TKinter GUI, it returns the row with the determined value, which indicates the syntax and dictionary is correct. It seems like the dictionary returns 'experiment_id' as a string to compare with, which is not what I am trying to do. Would there be a way to achieve what I am trying?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"WHERE experiment_id = experiment_id"` means where column experiment_id equals the column experiment_id. The version with `{'exp_id': 'experiment_id'}` means the actual string "experiment_id". You can't insert column names as query parameters: just put them in your query.

Comment: That's interesting. But as you can see, I need to be able to return the column with any value when my GUI leaves the entry empty, and also return the specific value when it is specified. How could I achieve that?

Comment: When the entry is empty, remove the WHERE clause.  When the entry has a value, then insert the actual value.

Comment: @Gardener is there a way to do that programatically? The user may or may not introduce all the values in the entry boxes. Thank you.